# Python: Add strings to a list full of integers

Tags: python, string, list, integer

Simple example:

I got a list full of integers which looks like this:

```
mylist1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print mylist1

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Now I want to add a string to every integer in the list. It should look like this afterwards:

```
['1 Hi', '2 How', '3 Are', '4 You', '5 Doing']
```

By now I should have a list full of strings. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Steps:**

You can convert int into string to append a string to it

i.e.) `print str(mylist1[0])+" hi did it"` gives you `1 hi did it`

To make in-place change in `list1` I used `enemurate` .If you can crate a new list @tomasz answer might help.

Just thinking that you have a list to update `list1`

**Code:**

```
mylist1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
mylist2=["hi","how","are","you","doing"]
for index,value in enumerate(mylist1):
    mylist1[index]="{} {}".format(str(value),mylist2[index])
print mylist1
```

**Output:**

```
['1 hi', '2 how', '3 are', '4 you', '5 doing']
```

**Notes:**

- Covert `int into string using str before appending`

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> mylist1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> mylist2 = ['Hi', 'How', 'Are', 'You', 'Doing']
>>> map(lambda x,y:str(x)+" "+y, mylist1,mylist2)
['1 Hi', '2 How', '3 Are', '4 You', '5 Doing']
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like:

```
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
myString = ['Hi', 'How', 'Are', 'You', 'Doing']

newList = []
for elem in zip(myList, myString): 
  newList.append(str(elem[0]) + ' ' + elem[1] )
```

To convert an integer into string you use the built-in method "str".

Answer (score 1):

Use [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) function and [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
mylist1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
mylist2 = ['Hi', 'How', 'Are', 'You', 'Doing']
print ['%d %s' % l for l in zip(mylist1, mylist2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be

```
list1 = [str(i) for i in range(1, 6)]
list2 = ['Hi', 'How', 'Are', 'You', 'Doing']
final_list = [' '.join(x) for x in zip(list1, list2)]
```